# ng-repeat overrides property in function but not in view model

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular and have a problem using my custom directive with ng-repeat. I want to display some posts I get from a rest interface and then use their _id property inside the directive for other purposes. However, it turns out that the property is always the one from the last displayed post when used from inside a function (test in the sample below). When trying to display the id directly over the viewmodel it shows the right one. Hope this makes sense. Any help would be appreciated.

```
//directive.js

angular.module('app').directive('gnPost', myGnPost);

function myGnPost() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: 'postCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'postCtrl',
        bindToController: {
            post: '='
        },
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'template.html'
    };
};

//controller.js

angular.module('app').controller('postCtrl', myPostCtrl);

function myPostCtrl(postRestService) {
    vm = this;
    vm.test = function () {
        return vm.post._id;
    };
};

// template.html

<p>{{postCtrl.post._id}}</p>
//displays the right id

<p>{{postCtrl.test()}}</p>
//displays the id of the last element of ng-repeat

//parent page.html

<gn-post ng-repeat="singlePost in posts.postList" post="singlePost"></gn-post>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, you have the following line:

```
vm = this;
```

It should be:

```
var vm = this;
```

By omitting the `var`, there is a `vm` variable created on the global scope instead of a local one per controller instance. As a result each iteration when `vm.test` is called, it's always pointing at the function defined on the last controller.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/14b6k67m/) - try including/omitting the `var` in `postCtrl`

It's good practice to use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) in Javascript to prevent that issue and others. In strict mode, it impossible to accidentally create global variables, as doing so will throw an error and you'll see the problem straight away. You just need to add this line at the start of your file or function:

```
"use strict";
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps. Did not notice the missing var.